# ios UITextView not appearing on map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uitextview

I'm adding a simple UITextView on top of a GMSMapView.
If you look at the text box, you can see that it's on top of the map.
Additionally, the UITextView is directly linked to the text view on the UI - has circle icon (o).
With this setup, I would expect the app to show something on the screen, but it's not apparently visible at all - see second image.

[image]

**Resulting map without visible UITextView**:

[image]

**My constraints**:

[image]

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: check your constraints first ,, if everything is fine then go for next step

Comment: I've updated the question to show my constraints - all blue lines, no issues.

Answer (score 1):

add the UITextView to mainView not the google map view, change the order should fix it

```
-- UIVIew

  -- UItextView 

  -- Map View
```